# If I forget after memorize the full Quran before dying, what Islam say about it?

Tags: quran, hadith, fiqh, sin

**Suppose** I memorize the  full Quran , If I forget before dying. What happen to me?

**As far as I know** people are who memorize the  full Quran (It's somethin like called as Quran a Hafeez or Hafeez  )

1. Is this sin?
2. Is there is any punishment for me?
3. Is there anything about in Quran or Hadith?
4. What Islam says about it?

Comment: It is not convenient to say I forgot the qur'an I memorized according the known hadith on the authority of ibn Mas'ud (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5039)). As for the question the scholars hold different opinions on the topic.

Comment: @Medi1Saif♦  It will help me if you provide hadith and reference  etc....

Comment: Added the hadith I'm actually not having the time to answer this.